# Bootstrap return previous state when clicked outside the page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-events

Here's a input field I've made, but I'm finding hard to return the input field to its previous state by clicking outside the form div. I'm trying to make something like twitter.com post input.

[Here's the jsfiddle link I've made](http://jsfiddle.net/soulsurfer/hsku2xt7/1/)

```js
 $('#askinput').click(function(){
      $(this).stop().animate({
        height:'100px'
    });
    $('#collapseExample').show();
    $('.ask-input-glyph').hide();
});
```

```css
#ask-form-div
{
    background-color: #F3EED8;
}
#askinput
{
    height: 44px;
}
.ask-input-glyph
{
    background-color: #4A6B69;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 3;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 21px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-11" id="ask-form-div">
                            <form role="form">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="formInput69"></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control text-right" id="askinput" placeholder="Placeholder text">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil ask-input-glyph"></i>
                                    <div id="collapseExample" style="display:none">
                                        <p>1. Climb a tree<input type="checkbox"/></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSFiddle Link -- Click this link..](http://jsfiddle.net/haridharan/hsku2xt7/2/)try this,`use focus and blur events`

```
$("#askinput").focus(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
       height:'100px'
    });
    $('#collapseExample').show();
    $('.ask-input-glyph').hide();
}).blur(function() {
   $(this).stop().animate({
      height:'44px'
   });
   $('#collapseExample').hide();
   $('.ask-input-glyph').show();
});
```